# Asymmetrical scheme: insecurity concerns of saving a hash of a hash of a password

Tags: hash, asymmetric

please verify or explain how to do this properly.

I'm letting a user create keys from the client through a secure server.

I ask the user for a password on the client, then send the hashed password to the server. The server generates fresh keys and encrypts them with the password hash + the generated verification key. The encrypted keys are saved on the server. I return the verification key to the client (Probably should encrypt this with the password hash as well, right?)

When the user needs to access their address to make a transaction or sign something, they must send the verification key and their password hash.

These keys and addresses are intended to be short-lived or one-time-use. However, I'm concerned that a user may forget their password and want to let them verify correctness before choosing a key to use. So, my plan is to save a hash of their password hash on the client database to confirm their password is correct before presenting them with an address to fund.

Is this sound and secure? What extra steps could I take to harden the process? If I'm wrongly reinventing a wheel, kindly suggest a protocol to follow.

Thanks for any attention and guidance!

Comment: What are the risks? What is the aim of those keys? Why they are not created locally and encrypted with the key derived from the user some other password.....

Comment: The keys will be generated through a secure mpc so that secret shares can be created and distributed according to the protocol. I'm thinking if the keys were created on the client, then the secret shares would become a point of insecurity or vulnerable target points.